# how to add captcha to Laravel 5.1 login?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

How can I add captcha/Google-reCaptcha to user auth login? there is only validation for register that I can modify, how can I modify validation for login?

my problem is not how to add recaptcha, my problem is how to add recaptcha validattion to login validation rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how I figure it out, I copied postLogin method from `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenicatesUsers.php` and edit it like bellow:

```
/**
 * Handle a login request to the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function postLogin(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->loginUsername() => 'required', 
        'password' => 'required',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|recaptcha'
    ]);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

    if ($throttles && $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

    if (\Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    if ($throttles) {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
        ->withInput($request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            $this->loginUsername() => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
        ]);
}
```

I've changed `Request` in method param to `\Illuminate\Http\Request` and `Auth` to `\Auth`. you can add these 2 at top of your file.

then I changed validation rules of login and add `'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|recaptcha'` in order to use Google recaptcha (https://github.com/greggilbert/recaptcha)

Answer (score 3):

Here's how i figured it out, for anyone else that also has this problem (using  http://github.com/greggilbert/recaptcha):

Copy the validateLogin function from vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php to app\http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php and just add the line to the array. You end up with this:

```
    /**
 * Handle a login request to the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function validateLogin(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->loginUsername() => 'required', 'password' => 'required','g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|recaptcha',
    ]);
}
```

That's it, captcha works now on login form. (You should ofcourse also add {!! Recaptcha::render() !!} in the login view)

Comment: Unfortunately this package is abandoned. So will need to update your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `vendor\laravel\ui\auth-backend\AuthenticatesUsers.php` and look for this function then add the new rule:

```
public function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->username() => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',

        // new rules here
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
        
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, overwrite the validateLogin found in the AuthenticatesUsers file, quick solution.

Comment: It's not good pratice to edit things on the vendor folder, the vendor folder should be ignored when moving or uploading Laravel projects and then it's re-downloaded by composer install on project installation

Answer (score 0):

You could use `greggilbert/recaptcha` package for Laravel-5. This github page explains how to use the package https://github.com/greggilbert/recaptcha

Comment: Thanks, my problem is not how to captcha, my problem is adding captcha validation to login validation.

Answer (score 0):

Use BotDetect CAPTCHA
for laravel 5.2 : https://captcha.com/doc/php/examples/laravel-auth-captcha-example.html#laravel_auth_controller

Answer (score -1):

You have to add this library via `composer.json`, then edit `views` and put the captcha code in it.

About Validation: you can make new rule and integrate it with Laravel validator or validate it in controller before or after laravel validation.

Comment: this library? which one?

Comment: you forget the link, by the way a nice package for google-recaptcha: https://github.com/greggilbert/recaptcha

Comment: please elaborate more